# is there a mapping of a sphere to a pseudosphere

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

I'm starting to study differential geometry. is there a mapping brings a sphere to a pseudosphere? the Riemann sphere mapping from the sphere to the complex plane makes me think there is one, but I can't see how to construct it

Comment: I imagine that by pseudosphere you mean the upper or lower part of it, right? That is, some of its parts seen as a regular surface. If you remove both poles from the sphere then it should be homeomorphic to the pseudosphere, at least that is what you would expect.

Comment: thank you. is there any advise on how to construct such a mapping?

Comment: Your question is too vague. It seems like you're looking for a differential geometry construction, but the metrics obviously will never correspond. If by pseudosphere you mean the two-sided pseudosphere (with a cuspidal edge joining them), then it is homeomorphic to a cylinder, which is in turn homeomorphic to a twice-punctured sphere. Writing down those mappings should not be hard for you.